# 特定の単語以外がマッチする正規表現

Tags: 正規表現

特定の単語以外がマッチする正規表現ができずに悩んでいます。

intではない単語を探したい場合に、下記のように記述しました。

```
\b((?!int).)*\b
```

この正規表現で下記を検索すると、すべて引っかかりません。

```
int integer interval
```

intは引っかかってほしくないが、integerやintervalを検索したいときにはどのような正規表現を使用すれば良いのでしょうか？

わかる方いらっしゃたらご教示お願い致します。

Comment: 正規表現のエンジンに何を使っているのか判然としないのですが、例えば `'\bint\w+'` など。

Answer (score 1):

perl準拠の正規表現として

> intは引っかかってほしくないが、integerやintervalを検索したいとき

が「int以外のintで始まる単語を検索したい」という意味なら

```
\bint\S+
```

「intではない単語を探したい」なら

```
\b(?!int)\S+|int\S+\b
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
intではない単語を探したいです（でした）。エンジンによって差が出てくるんですね。勉強になりました。